# Shopify iOS SDK error: Value of type 'Storefront.ShopQuery' has no member 'currencyCode'

Tags: ios, shopify

I'm getting started with Shopify's iOS sdk and in [following the official readme on GitHub](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/#fetch-shop-), I keep getting an error that I can't get rid of. I've followed the setup and pasted the example code line for line and I get This error no matter what project I try to use it on (full code in attachments)

> Value of type 'Storefront.ShopQuery' has no member 'currencyCode'

How can I fix this error?

```
import Buy
import Pay

class shopify {
    let client = Graph.Client(shopDomain: "-", apiKey: "-")
    
    func example() {
        let query = Storefront.buildQuery { $0
            .shop { $0
                .name()
                .currencyCode()
                .refundPolicy { $0
                    .title()
                    .url()
                }
            }
        }
        
        let task = client.queryGraphWith(query) { response, error in
            let name         = response?.shop.name
            let currencyCode = response?.shop.currencyCode
            let moneyFormat  = response?.shop.moneyFormat
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: @pkamb Please tell more about the issue, please make sure the version of SDK, ensure you are using the latest version .

Comment: @pkamb here is a link to the documentation, and a imgur of the exact section where the code is, its under "Case studies -> Fetch shop"

Github: https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/#fetch-shop-

image link: https://imgur.com/a/HdRu1I0

Comment: @MarcSteven ive checked and the version I am using is 7.0 which according to GitHub is the most up to date version. The core issue I'm trying to solve is that the code in its current form won't be compiled by Xcode, Xcode marks the line                (.  .currencycode()     ) 
with the error (.   Value of type 'Storefront.ShopQuery' has no member 'currencyCode'). 
according tot he documentation I am supposed to nest Currency code within shop but this results in said error

Answer (score 0):

You find this in paymentSetting, I guess

```
let query = Storefront.buildQuery { $0
        .shop { $0
            .name()
            .paymentSettings { $0
                .currencyCode()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).